# Can I share retryCount across policies in a PolicyWrap instead of them resetting?

Tags: c#, polly, retry-logic, policywrap

I currently have two retry policies configured for making some api calls which are being executed using a `PolicyWrap`:

- A WaitAndRetry policy for catching 429 rate limit errors and honoring the retry-after header
- A regular retry policy for handling timeouts/transient errors where waiting is not necessary and the call can be retried immediately

Is it possible to configure these to share the same retry counter? Say for example I wanted to configure 5 attempts to send the message regardless of which policy catches it.

Simplified example of my current configuration:

```cs
int maxAttempts = 5;

AsyncRetryPolicy RetryAfter = Policy
    .Handle<HttpResponseException>(e => e.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(retryCount: maxAttempts, i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

AsyncRetryPolicy RetryNow = Policy
    .Handle<HttpResponseException>(e => e.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout)
    .RetryAsync(retryCount: maxAttempts);

AsyncPolicyWrap ApiPolicy = Policy.WrapAsync(RetryNow, RetryAfter);
```

I'm using `onRetryAsync` to log the retry attempt. When it executes I get an output along the lines of the following where the `RetryAfter` policy resets it's retry counter whenever the `RetryNow` policy triggers.

```
Received error code ServerTimeout with internal status 408. Retry attempt #1
Received error code ServerError with internal status 429. Retry attempt #1 after 00:00:00.6010000
Received error code ServerTimeout with internal status 408. Retry attempt #2
Received error code ServerError with internal status 429. Retry attempt #1 after 00:00:00.5000000
Received error code ServerError with internal status 429. Retry attempt #2 after 00:00:00.3880000
Received error code ServerTimeout with internal status 408. Retry attempt #3
Received error code ServerError with internal status 429. Retry attempt #1 after 00:00:00.5230000
Received error code ServerTimeout with internal status 408. Retry attempt #4
Received error code ServerError with internal status 429. Retry attempt #1 after 00:00:00.5000000
Received error code ServerError with internal status 429. Retry attempt #2 after 00:00:00.1740000
Received error code ServerTimeout with internal status 408. Retry attempt #5
```

This means it's theoretically possible to have a total execution count far greater than the sum of configured `retryCount` on the policies. Ideally I would like this to execute a maximum of 5 retries total, but at this point I'd be happy to just have both policies honor their configured `retryCount` for a maximum of 10 retries. As It stands, the theoretical maximum with this configurations seems to be greater than 35 total: the 1 initial execution + (5 `RetryAfters` + 1 `RetryNow` repeated for every `RetryNow` attempt)

Am I doing something wrong with this? Is there a recommended way to handle this kind of situation? I'm still trying to get my head around the policy configuration so I assume I'm missing some kind of recommended/best practice here. This seems like a major oversight otherwise and surely I wouldn't be the only person to run into this problem if that were the case but I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1: Combine the two retry policies into one

You can handle both exceptions in one policy.  You can use the `.Or<>()` syntax to specify the second exception, and [this overload](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/5a5502b055248af43ca049ab1cabc91c4883da90/src/Polly/Retry/AsyncRetrySyntax.cs#L653-L654) to choose the duration of wait-before-retry based on the exception (and other factors):

```cs
AsyncRetryPolicy ApiPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<HttpResponseException>(e => e.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests)
    .Or<HttpResponseException>(e => e.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(retryCount: maxAttempts, 
        sleepDurationProvider: (i, ex, ctx) => 
            ex.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests 
                ? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) 
                : TimeSpan.Zero, 
        onRetryAsync: (ex, span, i, ctx) => /* whatever you have for logging */
    );
```

This retry policy will be limited to `1 + maxAttempts` tries overall, and reflects the retry delays in your original configuration.

---

#### Solution 2: Govern the overall execution time to curb 'excessive' retries

Alternatively, if you find it clearer still to express the two retries as separate policies (ie as the original `RetryAfter` and `RetryNow`), then another option is to wrap a `TimeoutPolicy` outside them.

That `TimeoutPolicy` will limit the overall duration of the combined execution - including all tries and waits between retries - providing a time-based way to prevent the combined retries multiplying unwantedly.

```cs
// RetryAfter and RetryNow exactly as in your question.  Then:

AsyncTimeoutPolicy OverallTimeout = Policy.TimeoutAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45));

IAsyncPolicy ApiPolicy = Policy.WrapAsync(OverallTimeout, RetryNow, RetryAfter);
```

If you want a timeout-per-try, you can also introduce that at the inner end of the PolicyWrap.

```cs
AsyncTimeoutPolicy OverallTimeout = Policy.TimeoutAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45));
AsyncTimeoutPolicy TimeoutPerTry = Policy.TimeoutAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

IAsyncPolicy ApiPolicy = Policy.WrapAsync(OverallTimeout, RetryNow, RetryAfter, TimeoutPerTry);
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why it didn't occur to me to handle them with one policy and just return a zero wait time. Guess I was trying to over-engineer my solution a little.